# How to make jar file including extended libraries in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I would like to create a exported jar file in Android studio,
but the problem here, the dependencies of gson , rxjava and retrofit did not include from the jar file, when i imported to other project

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'


    // API CONNECTION
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.3.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
task deleteJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'libs/logmanagementlib.jar'
}

task createJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('libs/jars/')
    include('classes.jar')

    rename('classes.jar', 'logmanagementlib.jar')

}

createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
```

can you give me a example how to include the compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1?

Comment: Include this compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1' in dependencies tag of build.gradle(Module:app). And the sync your project by clicking on right upper corner link sync now

Comment: I'm confusing, can u have a screenshot or any example, and is there way to include the manifest too?